Problem to run only C++ code in VS code.what can i do?
In my visual studio code , I can't run C/C++ code.But I install MinGw as well as add bin file to Path. Even I run gcc --version and gdp--version to check all is well. Everything is fine. But the problem arise when i run simple C/C++ code in VS code, it doesn't not run anything(even doesn't debugging).What can i do now?
Note: Previously i run python code in this vs code(code run finely).But problem arise only for C/C++ code. I uninstall python interpretor andreinstall VS code ....
This is error which shows
I try all which shows in internet and youtube but nothing changes


when i run simple C/C++ code you understand how run works? in a screenshot, in a terminal window error is clearly stated: 'cmd' is not recognized as... something wrong with your  tasks.json

Please see my task.json .This is my first time to set up C/C++

my dear friend, i want to make you feel confident in working with "all that hard programming, setting-up, configuring, installing... and i don't understand all that stuff... and i think it is not for me".  1) Identify the problem. On PCs it is text messages. Immidiate or logs. You have one in terminal window. 2) Search for narrowed problem. What it is in your case? look!  cmd is not recognized sound like it.  3) Google it. Find out that it is related to PATH. Oh! I did something to it recently. 4) Check correctness of the PATH. 5) How? Open terminal and print it echo %PATH%

open terminal and type cmd . it should open another (nested) terminal. If you see error... then it is in your PATH (thats how WinOS knows where to look for .dll, .exe files.
